# PHP: Use Google's SMTP relay with SwiftMailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp, swiftmailer

I want to use Google's [SMTP relay](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en) service as a SMTP server in PHP.

The IP address is whitelisted for the SMTP relay service, and I am using the [SwiftMailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/) as a PHP library to send emails.

I configured the SMTP service to use TLS encryption, and set the following parameters for the SwiftMailer:

```
transport: smtp
host: smtp-relay.gmail.com
port: 587
encryption: tls
auth_mode: login
```

I was able to send emails via telnet, but when I try to send emails with SwiftMailer with the above configuration, I receive the following error:

```
[CLOSED] IMAP connection broken (server response) (errflg=2)
```

How can I configure the SwiftMailer to use Google SMTP relay service as its SMTP server? Is it ever possible?

Answer (score 0):

had similar issue, when I provided the sender_address (that I'm checking on google relay server), it worked.
(I'm not using auth mode though, just IP source defined in google gsuite)

`swiftmailer:
  transport: smtp
  host:      smtp-relay.gmail.com
  port:      587
  encryption: tls
  sender_address: support@example.com`

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems to be not that well documented here is what worked for me after reading through different sources. Gmail itself wrote that it's important to send the HELO- or EHLO command, which can be done by setting the local domain (supported since swiftmailer-bundle 2.4.0). Otherwise you might run into DoS issues. See the official [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en) for more details.

```
transport:    smtp
host:         smtp-relay.gmail.com
port:         587
encryption:   tls
auth_mode:    login
username:     contact@yourdomain.com
password:     'yourpassword'
local_domain: yourdomain.com
```

Additionally I did add the IPv4 and the IPv6 address of my server within the Google Admin Console within the SMTP-Relay settings and activated TLS + SMTP-authentication, since I definitely want to have an encrypted connection between my server and gmail.